# Datatable redimensionar columnas arrastrando

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, css

compañeros tengo un inconveniente, los pongo al tanto, estoy trabajando en una vista donde el usuario tiene varios filtros que una vez consultados llenan una tabla, hay campos que se extienden mucho y me solicitan que en vez de ocultar los campos los pueda re-dimensionar arrastrando el borde de la columna, como en un excel, intente hacerlo con este plugin https://github.com/dobtco/jquery-resizable-columns, pero no lo he podido integrar de manera correcta, manejo bootstrap en version 4.3 y jquery en versión 3.3, manejo una plantilla de cabecera y otra de pie de pagina, pero aun así no función, conocen alguna manera que pueda funcionarme?
**Header**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="description" content="Herramienta de control de estanteria">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="author" content="Edison Salguero 3133328856">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#009688">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?= media();?>/images/favicon.ico"> <!-- Para cambiar el icono de la pestaña -->
  <title><?= $data['tag_page']?></title>
  <!-- Main CSS-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?= media();?>/css/main.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?= media();?>/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?= media();?>/css/style.css">
  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"> -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?= media();?>/css/jquery.resizableColumns.css">
</head>
<body class="app sidebar-mini">
  <!-- Navbar-->
  <header class="app-header"><a class="app-header__logo" href="<?= baseUrl();?>/Dashboard"><img src="<?= media(); ?>/images/Logo.png" alt=""></a>
    <!-- Sidebar toggle button--><a class="app-sidebar__toggle" href="#" data-toggle="sidebar" aria-label="Hide Sidebar"></a>
    <!-- Navbar Right Menu-->
    <ul class="app-nav">
      <!-- User Menu-->
      <li class="dropdown"><a class="app-nav__item" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-label="Open Profile Menu"><i class="fa fa-user fa-lg"></i></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu settings-menu dropdown-menu-right">
          <!-- <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="<?= baseUrl();?>/Opciones"><i class="fa fa-cog fa-lg"></i> Settings</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="<?= baseUrl();?>/Perfil"><i class="fa fa-user fa-lg"></i> Profile</a></li> -->
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="<?= baseUrl();?>/Logout"><i class="fa fa-sign-out fa-lg"></i> Logout</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </header>
  <?php require_once("Nav_admin.php");?>
```

**main**

```
<?php HeaderAdmin($data); ?>
<main class="app-content">
    <?php //getModal('modalAdministrativo',$data); 
        if (empty($_SESSION['permisosmod']['R'])) {
    ?>
    <p>Acceso Restringido</p>
    <?php 
        }else{ ?>
    <div class="app-title">
        <div>
            <h1><i class="fas fa-boxes"></i> <?= $data['tittle_page'];?></h1>
            <?php if ($_SESSION['permisosmod']['W']){ ?>
            <!-- <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" onclick="openModal();">Nuevo <i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i></button> -->
            <?php }?>
            <a href="<?= baseUrl(); ?>/Administrativo">Filtros de busqueda<i class="fas fa-search"></i></a>
        </div>
        <ul class="app-breadcrumb breadcrumb">
            <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="<?= baseUrl(); ?>"><i class="fa fa-home fa-lg"></i></a></li>
            <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="<?= baseUrl(); ?>/Administrativo">Base Administrativa</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="tile" id="filtrosadmin">
        <div id="divLoading">
            <div>
                <img src="<?= media(); ?>/images/loader.svg" alt="Loading">
            </div>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
          <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
            <a class="nav-link active" id="iIdCaja-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#iIdCaja" role="tab" aria-controls="iIdCaja" aria-selected="true">iIdCaja</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
            <a class="nav-link" id="CajaN-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#CajaN" role="tab" aria-controls="CajaN" aria-selected="true">iIcajaNum</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
            <a class="nav-link" id="Caja-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#Caja" role="tab" aria-controls="Caja" aria-selected="true">CAJA </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
            <a class="nav-link" id="IdCAL-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#IdCAL" role="tab" aria-controls="IdCAL" aria-selected="true">ID CARP-AZ-LIBRO</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
            <a class="nav-link" id="iIdent-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#iIdent" role="tab" aria-controls="iIdent" aria-selected="true">iIdentificacion</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
            <a class="nav-link" id="tObs-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#tObs" role="tab" aria-controls="tObs" aria-selected="true">tObservac</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
            <a class="nav-link" id="Fini-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#Fini" role="tab" aria-controls="Fini" aria-selected="true">Fecha inicial</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
            <a class="nav-link" id="Ffin-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#Ffin" role="tab" aria-controls="Ffin" aria-selected="true">Fecha final</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
            <a class="nav-link" id="Ttfin-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#Ttfin" role="tab" aria-controls="Ttfin" aria-selected="true">tTipoFinal</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
            <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="iIdCaja" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="iIdCaja-tab">
                <div class="tile">
                    <div class="card border-light mb-3 mx-auto" style="max-width: 50rem;">
                        <div class="card-header text-primary">Busqueda por Id de Caja</div>
                        <div class="card-body">             
                            <form name="formId" id="formId" action="" >
                                <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese el/los Id de caja" id="IdC" name="IdC" required></textarea>
                                <br>
                                <p><input type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary" /></p>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="CajaN" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="CajaN-tab">
                <div class="tile">
                    <div class="card border-light mb-3 mx-auto" style="max-width: 50rem;">
                        <div class="card-header text-info">Busqueda por Caja Numero</div>
                        <div class="card-body">             
                            <form name="formCN" id="formCN" action="" >
                                <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese el/los caja numero" id="NC" name="NC" required></textarea>
                                <br>
                                <p><input type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-info" /></p>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="Caja" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="Caja-tab">
                <div class="tile">
                    <div class="card border-light mb-3 mx-auto" style="max-width: 50rem;">
                        <div class="card-header text-success">Busqueda por Caja</div>
                        <div class="card-body">             
                            <form name="formCa" id="formCa" action="" >
                                <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese la/s caja/s" id="Ca" name="Ca" required></textarea>
                                <br>
                                <p><input type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success" /></p>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="IdCAL" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="IdCAL-tab">
                <div class="tile">
                    <div class="card border-light mb-3 mx-auto" style="max-width: 50rem;">
                        <div class="card-header text-dark">Busqueda por Id de carpeta/azeta/libro</div>
                        <div class="card-body">             
                            <form name="formcal" id="formcal" action="" >
                                <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese el/los Id a consultar" id="Cal" name="Cal" required></textarea>
                                <br>
                                <p><input type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-dark" /></p>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="iIdent" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="iIdent-tab">
                <div class="tile">
                    <div class="card border-light mb-3 mx-auto" style="max-width: 50rem;">
                        <div class="card-header text-danger">Busqueda por Identificación</div>
                        <div class="card-body">             
                            <form name="formiId" id="formiId" action="" >
                                <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese el/los Id a consultar" id="iId" name="iId" required></textarea>
                                <br>
                                <p><input type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-danger" /></p>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tObs" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tObs-tab">
                <div class="tile">
                    <div class="card border-light mb-3 mx-auto" style="max-width: 50rem;">
                        <div class="card-header text-dark">Busqueda por observaciones</div>
                        <div class="card-body">             
                            <form name="formObs" id="formObs" action="" >
                                <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese la frase a buscar o una palabra clave" id="obs" name="obs" required></textarea>
                                <br>
                                <p><input type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-dark" /></p>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="Fini" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="Fini-tab">
                <div class="tile">
                    <div class="card border-light mb-3 mx-auto" style="max-width: 50rem;">
                        <div class="card-header text-success">Busqueda por Fecha Inicial</div>
                        <div class="card-body">             
                            <form name="formFini" id="formFini" action="" >
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fini" name="fini" placeholder="dd/mm/aaaa" required>
                                <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Digite la fecha por la que desea consultar separado por "/"</small></p>
                                <br>
                                <p><input type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success" /></p>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="Ffin" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="Ffin-tab">
                <div class="tile">
                    <div class="card border-light mb-3 mx-auto" style="max-width: 50rem;">
                        <div class="card-header text-info">Busqueda por Fecha Final</div>
                        <div class="card-body">             
                            <form name="formFin" id="formFin" action="" >
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ffin" name="ffin" placeholder="dd/mm/aaaa" required>
                                <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Digite la fecha por la que desea consultar separado por "/"</small></p>
                                <br>
                                <p><input type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-info" /></p>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="Ttfin" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="Ttfin-tab">
                <div class="tile">
                    <div class="card border-light mb-3 mx-auto" style="max-width: 50rem;">
                        <div class="card-header text-primary">Busqueda Tipo Final</div>
                        <div class="card-body">             
                            <form name="formtT" id="formtT" action="" >
                                <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese el tipo final a consultar o una palabra clave" id="tTf" name="tTf" required></textarea>
                                <br>
                                <p><input type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary" /></p>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- tabla de base administrativa -->
    <div class="row" id="tabla">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="tile">
          <div class="tile-body">
            <div class="table-responsive">
              <table class="table table-bordered display pre" data-resizable-columns-id="demo-table-v2" cellpadding="0" width="100%" id="tableAdmin">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th data-resizable-column-id="Novedad">Novedad</th>
                    <th>Base Consolidada</th>
                    <th>Tentrega</th>
                    <th>Tpaquete</th>
                    <th>Iidcaja</th>
                    <th>Iicajanum</th>
                    <th>Caja</th>
                    <th>Serie</th>
                    <th>Id Carp-Az-Libro</th>
                    <th>Iidentificacion</th>
                    <th>Ifecha</th>
                    <th>Tobservac</th>
                    <th>Fecha Inicial</th>
                    <th>Fecha Final</th>
                    <th>Ttipofinal</th>
                    <th>Tomo</th>
                    <th>Folios</th>
                    <th>Mg</th>
                    <th>Tobservac</th>
                    <th>Adiciones</th>
                    <th>Unidad Contenedora</th>
                    <th>Piso</th>
                    <th>Linea</th>
                    <th>Modulo</th>
                    <th>Ubicacion</th>
                    <th>Accion</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>

                </tbody>
              </table>
              <script src="<?= media();?>/js/jquery.resizableColumns.min.js"></script>
              <script>
                $(function(){
                  $("table").resizableColumns({
                    store: window.store
                  });
                });
              </script>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
</main>
<?php FooterAdmin($data); ?>
```

**Footer**

```
 <script>
        const baseUrl = "<?= baseUrl();?>";
    </script>
    <!-- Essential javascripts for application to work-->
    <script src="<?= media();?> /js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="<?= media();?>/js/plugins/chart.js"></script>
    <script src="<?= media();?>/js/plugins/chartjs-plugin-datalabels.js"></script>
    <script src="<?= media();?> /js/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="<?= media();?> /js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="<?= media();?> /js/main.js"></script>
    <script src="<?= media();?> /js/Fontawesome.js"></script>
    <!-- The javascript plugin to display page loading on top-->
    <script src="<?= media();?> /js/plugins/pace.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Data table plugin-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?= media();?>/js/plugins/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?= media();?>/js/plugins/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?= media();?>/js/plugins/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>

    <script src="<?= media();?>/js/<?= $data['functions_js_page'];?>"></script>
    <!-- Page specific javascripts-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?= media();?> /js/plugins/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image: pantalla]

Comment: Un truco sería traerte los datos desde tu consulta. Supongamos que te traes un registro donde en un campo viene un texto demasiado largo. Bueno, primero desde la base de datos o desde donde tú quieras vas a imprimir los primeros 30 caracteres. Por ejemplo con php sería algo así como <span data-full-text="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($tu_string); ?>" class="show-full-text"><?php echo substr($tu_string, 0, 30);  ?></span> Luego, con javascript, crea un evento para la clase .show-full-text para que al darle click, sustituya el valor de ese span por el original que viene en data-full-text

Comment: Revisa [esta discusión](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/63231/resizing-columns-using-jquery-ui) en los foros de DataTables, podría ser útil.

Comment: @Triby exactamente esa fue la solución correcta, permite hacer lo que el usuario requería.
Muchas gracias también FernandoTorres
Aquí dejo el link para futuros developers
https://github.com/jeffreydwalter/ColReorderWithResize